Composable AlertDialog not changing to DarkMode
In my Compose activity, I have following AlertDialog:
AlertDialog(
    title = { Text(text = dialogTitle) },
    text = { Text(text = dialogDescription) },
    confirmButton = {}
)

It looks like this:

The problem is, that I would like this AlertDialog to support light/dark mode. Now, it is always white (light). I have tried to create Modifier where I changed background, but it does not work. Can somebody help me solve this issue? I did not find any specific guide to AlertDialogs in official documentation. Thank you.

You need to pass color from app theme into containerColor parameter. Somehting like this: containerColor = AppTheme.colorScheme.containerNormalOnSurface

set containerColor, titleContentColor,textContentColor based on your theme
AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = {},
        confirmButton = {},
        modifier = Modifier,
        dismissButton = { },
        icon = {},
        title = { Text(text = "Test title") },
        text = { Text(text="Test Description") },
        containerColor = Color.Black,
        iconContentColor = AlertDialogDefaults.iconContentColor,
        titleContentColor = Color.White,
        textContentColor = Color.White,
        tonalElevation = AlertDialogDefaults.TonalElevation,
    )

Result will be

